# How to write a validation rule that throws an error when a field value was already inserted?

Tags: apex, trigger, validation-rule, validation, fields

There is a field CreatedById.

I want to throw an error if there are already values with the same CreatedById values.

How can I write such a validation rule?

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/384958/edit) your question to add what you have tried (it's OK if it fails) and how it is not working (e.g., *exact* error text). This site exists to *help*, not do the work. (From the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section of Help Center: *"We’re not a place to exchange code or find implementation services."*) Please read more of the Help Center, and also take the [Tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little ambiguous.

Do you mean one of the following?

**1.** You want to check other fields on the record for the same value as the CreatedById.

This is pretty straightforward. Your validation rule could look something like this "CreatedById == LastModifiedById". Sub any field for LastModifiedById. You can check multiple fields in one validation rule.

**2.** You want to see if any other records have the same value for CreatedById.
This would not be possible via validation rule. You only have access to the current record(and lookup values). To achieve this you could create a flow or Apex Trigger.